# Can you manually overwrite a field that has a calculated value assigned to it in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I am new to Blazor and have made a  form where a user is able to enter a value. That value is then multiplied by 100 to give a total and is stored in another field. The issue I am having is that I want to be able to edit the total value. So if a user enters 5 in the Price field, it will display 500 in the total field, but I want to be able to change that 500 value without affecting the Price field entry. Where I am confused is how that would work as Total = Price*100, so every time an edit is made, it goes back to the original value. Could anyone tell me what I could possible do? I am using the MudTable component

PriceViewModel:

```
 public class PriceViewModel
    {
public int PriceId{get;set;}
public decimal? Price{get;set;}
public decimal? Total{get;set;}
}
```

my form:

```
    <MudTable OnCommitEditClick="Save" Items="Products" Hover="true" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Sm" Loading="@_loading" LoadingProgressColor="Color.Info">
        <HeaderContent>
            <MudTh>Price</MudTh>
            <MudTh>Total</MudTh>
        </HeaderContent>
        <RowTemplate>
    @{
    decimal totalprice= (context.Price??0)*100;
    }
            <MudTd DataLabel="Price">@context.Price</MudTd>
            <MudTd DataLabel="Total" @onclick="@(()=>Edit(@context.PriceId))">@Math.Round(totalprice,3)</MudTd>
        </RowTemplate>
    <RowEditingTemplate>
 @{
    decimal totalprice= (context.Price??0)*100;
    }
     <MudTd Style="text-align:center" Class="pa-0" DataLabel="Price">
                <MudNumericField Format="0.0" Style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center; " @bind-Value="@context.Price" Required HideSpinButtons="true" /></MudTd>
     <MudTd Style="text-align:center" Class="pa-0" DataLabel="Total">
                <MudNumericField Format="0.0" Style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center; " @bind-Value="@context.Total" Required HideSpinButtons="true" /></MudTd>
    </RowEditingTemplate>
    </MudTable>

    @code{
        private void Edit(int id)
        {
            viewModel= PriceViewModel.FirstOrDefault(c => c.PriceId== id);
        }
    }
```

I am not sure if the information provided I enough and I apologize if it is not, I will update question if it is. Thank you in advance

Comment: Please include `PriceViewModel` (the relevant parts).

Comment: @PoulBak sorry about that, I have updated the question

Comment: Well, why do you need `totalprice`? Can't you simple set `context.Total`?

Comment: @PoulBok Oh yes, that would be the same thing, But the same result would happen as You wont be le to change the value of context.Total :(